# Webscraping latitude longitude from google results

Tags: python, web-scraping

How can I scrape latitude and longitude from the google results in the image below using beautiful soup.

Google result latitude longitude

[image]

Comment: This is not text output but I have attached the google result screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for do it with bs4:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36',}
response = get("https://www.google.com/search?q=latitude+longitude+of+75270+postal+code+paris+france",headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
a = soup.find("div", class_= "Z0LcW").text
print(a)
```

Comment: Yes, but OP asked for beautiful soup :-x

Comment: I changed it for bs4

Comment: Thanks for the answer this really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more input on further questions since we don't want to do the pre-work to create a solution.

You will have to grab this container:

```
<div class="HwtpBd gsrt PZPZlf" data-attrid="kc:/location/location:coordinates" aria-level="3" role="heading"><div class="Z0LcW XcVN5d">48.8573° N, 2.3370° E</div><div></div></div>
```

**BS4**

```
#BeautifoulSoup Stuff
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


# Make the request
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=latitude+longitude+of+75270+postal+code+paris+france&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE740DE740&oq=latitude+longitude+of+75270+postal+code+paris+france&aqs=chrome..69i57.4020j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"

        response = requests.get(url)

        # Convert it to proper html
        html = response.text

        # Parse it in html document
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

        # Grab the container and its content
        target_container = soup.find("div", {"class": "Z0LcW XcVN5d"}).text
```

Then you have a string inside the div returned.

..Assuming google doesn't change the class declarations randomly. I tried five refreshes and the classname didn't change, but who knows.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents' this error is coming up.

Comment: didnt use BS4 for ages feels like, then it is probably .text

Comment: .text is also showing error but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using `user-agent` (you can also use `python` `fake user-agents` library)

Code and [replit.com](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Latitude-Longitude-from-Google-Search-Results#main.py) that grabs location from Google Search results:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=latitude longitude of 75270 postal code paris france',
                    headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

location = soup.select_one('.XcVN5d').text

print(location)
```

Output:

```
48.8573° N, 2.3370° E
```